# How to confirm delivery of Amazon-SNS Message to SQS Queue?

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm publishing a message to SNS, and then delivering that message to an SQS queue.  If I have the PublishResult from publishing the message (containing a MessageId), is there any way I can confirm delivery to the SQS queue without interacting with the SQS queue itself?

Link to docs in case I'm missing something obvious:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/Welcome.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/gsg/Welcome.html

Comment: Once you subscribe your queue to a topic then why do you need a confirmation of delivery. AWS guarantees to deliver you notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to get notified or query the status of an in flight message.  SNS guarantees delivery to SQS, so the message will eventually get there.